# Using Cypress 6.4 wait for interception but skip first canceled xhr call

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cypress, intercept

I using intercept to wait for the XHR call and be sure the app grid it is loaded to start to do my tests:

```
cy.visit('/contacts')
cy.intercept('POST', '**/contacts/datatable').as('getContacts')
cy.wait('@getContacts')
cy.log('now I can start...')
```

The problem is that I for some problem with the api I get first a canceled XHR and then a 200 status with the correct response and cypress get stuck in the cy.wait.

I have try to add some kind of condition like:

```
cy.wait('@getContacts')
  .should('have.property','response.statusCode',200)
  .then(cy.log('now I can start...'))
```

But still the same.

Any ideas to skip the XHR calls until the response it is 200 ?

Comment: Call `cy.intercept` before calling `cy.visit`. From what I've seen, your browser might be trying to visit the link before the API has been mocked.

Comment: did you try failOnStatusCode? I guess it will solve your problem: see documentation https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Arguments

Answer (score 0):

Try to chain wait with should(). i.e:

```
cy.wait('@getContacts').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200).
```

according to the cypress documentation, cy.wait will wait until the status code is 200.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is correct but the issue is that get pointed to the first request that the status is (canceled) and when the second request to the same address retrurn 200 and the correct data cypress ignore it.  so even i can see the data in the grid i get an error in the cy.wait and the execution of the test stops

Comment: FYI guys you can ask your questions directly in cypress channel -> https://discord.gg/5X52D2gq